# Can build_site() not overwrite .gitignore in public/?

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm following the suggestion on [this section](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/github-pages.html) to put the `public/` folder under version control. Hugo seems to generate an automatic .gitignore files every time I build the site. The default .gitignore ignores everything except itself. Now after I run `build_site()`, I need to manually overwrite the default .gitignore for the changes to show up.

Is there an option that can turn off the overwriting of .gitignore?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. In my installation, there is no generation of a .gitignore file. Do you have a .gitignore file in your content folder? if yes: delete it. Use "clean all" before you rebuild the site.

Comment: @PeterBaumgartner That would be my guess, too. Things under `content/` and `static/` will be copied to `public/`, but `.gitignore` under the root directory should not be copied. BTW, I think I have said enough times that [Netlify is a better option than Github Pages](https://yihui.name/en/2017/06/netlify-instead-of-github-pages/). If you deploy through Netlify, you wouldn't need to worry about `public/` at all.

Comment: I created the site using `new_site(theme = "jbub/ghostwriter")`. I just created a dummy site using the same command and there's indeed a `.gitignore` file in `static/`. It seems to be a copy of [this file](https://github.com/jbub/ghostwriter/blob/master/exampleSite/static/.gitignore) in the original repo. Setting `theme_example` to `FALSE` seems to exclude the file.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem when generating my site with a theme I forked from github. I use `git` to to track changes in the course files and then to push the generated site to GitHub where the site is hosted. I created a `.gitignore` file in the source files for the hugo site so it would ignore `.DS_Store` and `.icloud` files but when I ran `hugo -D`, the `.gitignore` file in the generated site repo would also be modified but appear empty.

The issue was that there was extra `.gitignore` files lurking in the template and theme files that I had forked. Deleting them with and regenerating the site files from source without running `hugo mod clean --all` fixed the issue.